# Extraction of one element from numpy?

Tags: numpy

I have a Numpy array of shape (50x10x12x12)
Now I want to extract one element from first dimension i.e 50 which would have shape of (10x12x12).

What will be the code for this?

Answer (score 1):

Extract number 20 with:

```
N[20, :, :, :]
```

where `N` is your 4-dimensional array.

You can also write this as:

```
N[20, ...]
```

which will work for a multidimensional array with an arbitrary number of dimensions.  The `...` is the Ellipsis symbol.  The results for both operations are identical.

Comment: @kazemakase I wouldn't want to recommend writing this as `N[20]`.  A reader may confuse it with `N.ravel()[20]` or `N[..., 20]`.  Explicit is better than implicit.  It doesn't help that Matlabs behaviour is different in case of indexing a multi-dimensional array with a single number.